# Include the check boxes before selected angular js

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, input

Is it possible to include all check boxes in the list if one is selected. For example, 10 checkboxes on the page and we check the 5th - so 1,2,3,4,5 should be checked.
Does anybody have an example of this with angular JS?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try something (hint: `ngChange` or `$scope.$watch`) and come back again with some code.

Comment: Can find examples in a google search ... this site isn't google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Blackhole, a possible solution would be using ng-change on your checkboxes.

your html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="bx in boxes" ng-model="bx.value" ng-change="boxChecked($index, bx.value)">
```

in controller:

```
$scope.boxChecked = function(index, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    $scope.boxes[i].value = value;
  }
}
```